# C# design dump/overview? Class stats

Tags: c#

Is there a way i can see stats on my class design? This project grew pretty big and i am sure it is messy but so far *for me* its easy to maintain. Is there a way i can see the count of methods on each class, how many classes i have and how many static members i have etc? (hopefully i only have static methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a static analysis tool for C#.

One commercial offering that lets you query many aspects of your code is [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Wikipedia has a list - [tools for static code analysis (.NET)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#.NET).